# Wrong Listing Question to a Specific Tag

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags, caching

Well today while surfing Question's inside the "C#" tag there where a Question or Entry which was tagged to 'opencv' and 'php' but it was listed at C# section.

You can see the image below :
[image]

You can see in the Link that tagged Question should be only with C# but that one has not the Condition to be listed there.

The question im talking is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213220/some-image-editing-examples-needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *was* listed as [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and it was edited to remove the tag. However, it appears the cache for the Newest C# Tagged Questions was not updated yet.

[image: It had the tags]

Comment: Indeed: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9213220/revisions

Comment: Looks like it has just been updated. This is a completely normal side effect of caching.