# What is caching, and where is it used?

Tags: support, faq-proposed, caching

> This is meant to be a canonical Q&A for all the caching questions we get on meta

- What is caching?
- Where is caching employed across the network?
- Approximately how long ought it take for each cache to update?

Comment: "What is caching?" Have you bothered researching at all? Plus, how is that on topic for MSO?

Comment: See also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-overflow-use-caching-and-if-so-how

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: yeah, already linked to it in the answer

Comment: @Manishearth: Sorry, didn't spot that!

Comment: @Manishearth I'd say George's link is the canonical one. If you want to create a FAQ, editing that one into shape might be a better approach perhaps?

Comment: @Bart: hmm, I could try that. Bit busy now, feel free to move everything over yourself if you wish :)

Comment: Nice one, until this is completed I've added new entry to the [glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/152859). :)

Comment: @Manishearth I was attempting to edit the other one....let's say I would end up doing more damage than good. I'll leave it as it is. :)

Comment: @Bart: More or less why I didn't incorporate it when I found that question and was still drafting this :)

Comment: Caching information on **caching**...

Answer (score 5):

### What is caching?

[Caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) is the storing of dynamic data in static form for reasonable periods of time. This reduces the number of queries required to display a page. The Stack Exchange engine caches heavily in places, to minimize cross-site queries. It uses [Redis](http://redis.io/) to help facilitate this. There is more on how exactly SO caches [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/178438).

### Where is caching employed, and approximately how long should it take for the cache to update?

- [Number of questions in a tag, on the tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153412/learn-tag-shows-zero-questions-tagged)
- [Rep/badges in the reputation leagues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178593/178438)
- Reputation on meta
- New questions and [number of answers on a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147324/there-is-a-time-delay-on-number-of-answers) on the main page
- [Assignment of questions to tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121801/wrong-listing-question-to-a-specific-tag)
- Tags are cached for searches and a post may still show up in a tag search after the tag is edited out
- On a user's profile:

  - Rep/Badges on other sites
  - Score/count in a tag ([Once a day, ~3am UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178115/178438))
  - "Votes Cast" ([5 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296916/152859))
- Flair
- Reputation counts on SO Careers ([~1 day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81585/178438))
- Rep/badges on chat profile (can be force-refreshed by a moderator)
- Moderator status on chat

Comment: Also chat profiles may not update instantly when a user gets enough rep to chat.

Comment: related: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/165773)

Comment: the post entitled: "Rep/badges in the reputation leagues" is deleted.