# When or how often does Area51 update for beta sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I have noticed that Area51 updates are somewhat offset by ~1 day UTC. I would like to know exactly or approximately how often it is updated, I have looked around, there is no mention in the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and it has [never](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=area51%20update) [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51) [brought](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=area51%20update) [up](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=update) before it seems.

I have also noticed that it is out of sync with the *Site Stats* on beta sites <strike>and often, reputation is updated there for top users but not total questions answered etc</strike>.

The closest is I have gotten to an answer is this [question about caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178596/what-is-caching-and-where-is-it-used) and it isn't mentioned there either.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat confusing. But I can tell you that the Stack Exchange devs are working on an updated version of Area 51 (aptly named "Area 52" for the moment). That's the reason why things like flag reasons, mobile site, consecutive days, help center, etc. aren't updated, or at least they are updated way later.

Robert sums it up quite nicely [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8922/72755).

Also, at the bottom of the page, there is a centered piece of text that basically says the version. It is conveniently put as a date:

[image: rev 2013.7.21.167]

Comment: Most [recent update](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/8921/is-a-new-area-51-site-under-development?rq=1). I think its still in the concept/design phase and development hasnt yet kicked off.