# Deleted questions remain in the "Questions" listing

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, question-lists, caching, newest-questions

Very recently, a "question" containing profanity and an attack on all users of Stack Overflow was posted. The question was deleted (removed?) within 2 minutes of its posting. However, this did not immediately remove it from the listing of newest questions I viewed by clicking on the "Questions" button on the website.

Is there some kind of known delay in removing such a "question" from that listing? Or is this a bug? I imagine no one wants to have to view such a thing even briefly -- is there a technical challenge in immediately removing it from the list?

(FYI, the offensive material was visible in the title and display text in the list -- not only if you clicked on the question).

Comment: Sounds like it just lingered around in a cache somewhere along the line.

Comment: The listings are cached. Deleted questions remain listed for a little while in that cache. That is normal behaviour.

Comment: See [Does Stack Overflow use caching and if so, how?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69164) and [What is caching, and where is it used?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178596)

Comment: Doh! I searched for any similar questions.  Sorry about the duplicate.

Comment: Dang it! I missed an opportunity to be offended? Are you sure it was an attack on **ALL** users, and not just **MOST** users?

Comment: It did in fact attack `all` SO users ("developers").  It was pretty lame.