# Tags for a badge; 5=6?

Tags: support, tags

So I have a question about getting a badge. On Math.SE, I have two answers both with 3 upvotes. Both of those had the calculus tag. I am confused about why, on the badge page for calculus, it says that I only have 5 there. Explanation

Comment: Probably caching.

Comment: @AlE. What is caching?

Comment: [What is caching, and where is it used?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178596/21960)

Comment: [Does Stack Exchange use caching and if so, how?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69164/21960)

Comment: [Cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing))

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You now have three answers: Two with a score of +3 and one with a score of +2. The older two were ones with +3 and +2; the second +3 was added <24 hours ago. Therefore, the system has not yet processed it, and the +5 is the total of the first +3 and the +2.

This is called caching. See [Does Stack Exchange use caching and if so, how?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how), [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms?lq=1), [What is caching, and where is it used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178596/what-is-caching-and-where-is-it-used?lq=1) and links therein.

Comment: So it will come up later?

Comment: @0.5772156649... Yes, it should, probably within a day or so (although this can vary).

Comment: Good to know, just still learning the features

Comment: I just forgot about that last other question

Comment: @0.5772156649... Yeah, that seems to have been (part of) the issue.

Comment: @0.5772156649... http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @0.5772156649... Tag scores are updated at 03:00 UTC every day.

Comment: @animuson **should** be updated every day. But it [breaks often](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run) so many times it will  take more than one day.