# Suffrage awarded but still votes cast is zero

Tags: support, bug, badges, voting

See the image below: I was awarded the Suffrage badge (awarded when we use 30 votes in a day), but still the number of votes cast is zero.

[image: Suffrage badge]

Comment: What bug are you reporting. you didn't casted any votes and the badge awarded by mistake (or) you casted 30 votes but its not showing?

Comment: I have already casted 32 votes and then surffage badge was awarded but number of votes didn't changed in votes cast

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a cache item got stuck with the wrong value - it is supposed to be a 5 minute cache, but for some reason it didn't clear properly, meaning the "votes cast" was still incorrectly showing as 0 instead of the correct value.

I manually deleted the cache item, which has resolved the immediate issue. I will treat this as an isolated case for now (if we get more reports of such cache items not clearing when they should be, we shall have to investigate further).

Answer (score 2):

It's a caching issue - The "votes cast" isn't updated immediately, only periodically. You've probably cast enough votes, earning you the badge, but the "votes casts" just wasn't updated yet. If you wait a few hours you should see it updated.

Comment: FYI, the badge was earned 14 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/804/suffrage?userid=5078003

Comment: This is wrong, as Oded says [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6086719#6086719), the cache is for five minutes only.